# How to upload all images when "overflow:hidden" is set for the uploaded area?

Tags: php, html, css

I try to write image gallery without use any libraries. I want to upload 14 jpg files as "uniq_image" instances into common image "moving_image". The bug that I succeed to upload only 3 jpg files because "overflow:hidden" is set for 'td' class in css.

The css file:

```
//the common long horizontal image that I want to assemble from uniq_images
#moving_image  {
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    position: relative;
    border:1px dashed red;
    width: 420px;
    height: 130px;
    left: 10px;
}
//the style for each uploaded image from the file
.uniq_image {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border:1px solid gray;
    width: 120px;
    height: 80px;
    margin: 5px 25px 5px 25px;
    padding:2px
    overflow:hidden;
}
//I set it because I have to fix the cell size
td {
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

The html code:

```
....
<td width ="420" height="130" overflow="hidden">
     <div id= "moving_image" >
             <?php
                  $img_folder = 'picture';
                  $dir = dir($img_folder);
                  while (($file = $dir->read()) !== false){
                      echo '<img src="'.$img_folder."/".$file.'" class="uniq_image" >';              
                  $dir->close();
              ?>
      </div>
<td>
```

So, how can I fix this bug and upload all images into "moving_image"? Thanks.

Comment: Ummm.... remove the width from the table cell so it could grow? Your question boils down to "how can I stop hitting myself in the face?" ... by stopping.

Comment: Hi Mark, this is the last issue in my image gallery. it wil be done after this fix.I can't remove td width because it shouldn't grow and have to be with the fixed width 420px. What do you mean?

Comment: How about removing the height and adding a break after each image? `echo '<img src="'.$img_folder."/".$file.'" class="uniq_image" ><br/>'`

Comment: @tatiana: you've got a fixed-size box on your screen, and are asking how to make it fit more. Either make the box bigger, or put in fewer things. There's no middle ground.

Comment: Hi Mrtsherman, I need a long horizontal image "moving_image" that I could to scroll to left and to right directions. The td height should be also fixed to 130px.

Comment: Mark, the idea is to scroll "moving_image" image. When I begin to scroll it, it doesn't have additional 11 "uniq_image" images that should be there.

Comment: What you need to do is use javascript by the sounds of it to create a carousel. It won't be the php code. Try googling for "jquery carousel" or "jquery slideshow" you will need to couple this with relative and absolute positioning probably, manipulating the "left" values of the images. The relative positioning should be on the "moving_image" div and this should have the overflow I think. Can't quite recall if <td> plays nice with relative...

Comment: @TommyBs, this is the exercise that I received. The task is "not to use jquery or other libraries". I can try to write something with javascript in moveLeft() and moveRight() functions, but I want to believe that it has a simpler solution with css definition.

Comment: @TommyBs I didn't understand about relative position and td. What do you mean?

Comment: Then I'm afraid I have to agree with the other comments. I don't see how this can be accomplished with overflow:hidden and with images that are larger then the area. You either shrink the images or increase the size. Failing that you need overflow:scroll or a javascript solution.
Alternatively, you left and right links could link to the same page with a $_GET parameter. This defines the offset. e.g if($_GET['offset']){ //do some calculation here and use absolute positioning again to move images along }

This would reload the page though

Comment: using the css of "position:relative" doesn't always work properly. And if you were using absolute positioning on the images then you would need to set the parent <div> as position:relative. not the <td>

Comment: @TommyBs thanks for the answer. Possibly it is good idea with $_GET. I'll try to write something.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue. I added:

```
margin-left:-2000px;
width:2000px;
```

to "moving_image" definition.